# Laravel ORM: Query without table prefix

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I'm working on a project where I have to integrate with some tables form wordpress and other systems. To setup the database for my Laravel project I chose to use table a prefix and for my project tables it's working fine.

My problem is when I have to work with tables from other systems using Laravel. For example, the query below adds my project's table prefix to it:

```
$item = DB::table('cnp_item')
                ->where('code', $row[1])
                ->first();
```

Instead of querying the `cnp_item` table it's querying `laravel_cnp_item` table, which does not exist.

I know it makes sense since I configured a table prefix. My question is if there is anything I could do in some queries to make it ignore my table prefix.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could define a different a different connection in `config/database.php` that omits the `prefix` setting:

```
'connections' => [
  'mysql' => [
    ...
    'prefix' => 'laravel',
    ...
  ], 'alternate' => [
    ...
    'prefix' => '',
    ...
  ]
],
```

Then, if you want to query a table that doesn't have that connection, switch to it on the fly using `DB::connection()`:

```
$item = DB::connection('alternate')->table('cnp_item')->where('code', $row[1])->first();
```

Or, if you use a `Model`, you *should* be able to define the `connection` and `table`, so you'd simply have to do:

```
class CNPItem extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'alternate';
  protected $table = 'cnp_items';
  ...
}
```

Then you'd simply query like so:

```
$item = CNPItem::where('code', $row[1])->first();
```